# Can we use std::reduce to subtract?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17, reduce, accumulate

I discovered the [`std::reduce` algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) recently and wanted to compare it with `std::accumulate`. I found [this blog post](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/accumulate-vs-reduce/#:%7E:text=However%2C%20if%20we%20try%20to%20use%20std%3A%3Areduce%2C%20we%20could%20get%20something%20like%3A) explaining how `std::reduce` can be parallelised using `std::execution::par`. However, the blog post notes that parallelisation only works with operations that are "both associative and commutative."

I wanted to test this out. While I originally thought that subtraction failed due to the algorithm being parallelised, I discovered that it seems `std::reduce` doesn't give the correct answer for subtraction even when used with `std::execution::seq` or just run without an execution policy (which should run the algorithm sequentially).

Running this:

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
auto diff = std::reduce(begin(vec), end(vec), 0, std::minus<>{});
std::cout << diff << "\n";
```

Gives this output:

```
-1
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or does `std::reduce` just never work with subtraction?

Comment: Not an answer, but a thought: how is this different from negating the result of summing the vector?

Comment: Reading the docs you linked indicates that the elements can be taken in arbitrary order, that doesn't work for subtraction.

Comment: @Chris it doesn't and I think this is the best method! I was just wondering about the underlying reasoning

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Thanks that makes sense! I assumed that that only happened for parallelisation but I guess I should've read the docs more closely.

Comment: [`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce): "The behavior is non-deterministic if binary_op is not associative or not commutative." (And 5 - (4 - (3 - (2 -1))) is probably not what you intended, anyway.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, with a very slight modification to the calculation.
You need to leave the first value out of reduce, and subtract the sum of the other elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <execution>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    auto sum_of_rest = std::reduce(std::execution::par, vec.begin() + 1, vec.end());
    auto diff = vec.front() - sum_of_rest;
    std::cout << diff << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the `std::execution::par` meant to be illustrative only? you wouldn't use execution policies for just 5 elements normally.

Comment: @JanSchultke Correct illustration only. And I totally agree for small sets (but not even this small) probably unseq (vectorization) but not par ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what a "correct" result should be when using a non-commutative or non-associative operation.  Given that the operations may be performed in any order, there are many possible results for the operation of "subtracting all elements", and the standard [specifically states](https://eel.is/c++draft/reduce#9):

> The difference between `reduce` and `accumulate` is that `reduce` applies `binary_op` in an unspecified order, which yields a nondeterministic result for non-associative or non-commutative `binary_op` such as floating-point addition.

- [[numeric.ops]/[reduce] p9](https://eel.is/c++draft/reduce#9)

Comment: @Jan, integer subtraction is non-commutative, which is exactly why this answers the question.